# Enum to get fixed values and dont use Maps

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have few permissions and each permission has some value like View-2, OWN-1, EDIT-4 ,etc. Now I wanted to get this value based upon permission but I dont want to use MAPS. I have done it as following

```
public enum Permissions
{
    OWN(1), VIEW(2), EDIT(4), DELETE(8), CREATE(16),SUGGEST(32);

    private int permissionValue;

    private Permissions(int value)
    {
        this.permissionValue = value;
    }

    public int getPermissionValue()
    {
        return permissionValue;
    }
}
```

So to get the value I call `getPermissionValue()` method. So my question is:

Is there any better way to achieve this with or without enums but no maps? If yes , please help.

Comment: i don't get what you want to do. do you want to get the enum value?

Comment: I want to get the permission value like if I say View I want to get value 2

Comment: I don't see Maps in you example. Please paste the code calling the Enum.

Comment: Just use integers, so you can use bit-Operations. What do you do if one has permission `VIEW` and `EDIT`? You need some List<Permissions> but with integers you can use `VIEW|EDIT`

Comment: @Fildor when user has edit, then view is automatic, and it gets a value od view + edit . ie 2+4 =6

Comment: I see. So you don't store Permissions - you store ints and use the enum as constants. I don't see why a map should do a better job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply call getPermissionValue() on the object.

so this might be the best attempt

Comment: Yes, that is what I am currently doing, Just confirming if there is any better way.

Answer (score 1):

Use [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) on an enum with default constructors. Call the enum Permission, call the EnumSet Permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The decision if you use an enum or a own class implementing this functionality using a Map should be based on the necessity of extensibility:

Is it expected that "Permissions" may often change/ new ones added? Most importantly, you need to ask yourself if in future the "Permissions" will be edited/created at runtime by user or not.

-> If the "Permission" are fixed, then you should go for the enum like you proposed.

-> If it might be possible that users need to be able to create/change Permissions it would be a good idea to model them as custom entities and NOT using an enum.